# Wordpress 6.2 php8.1 Ubuntu Server 22.04

Tags: server, apache2, php, wordpress

I have WP 6.2 installed on a LAMP stack(bare metal) and running php8.1 on an Ubuntu Server 22.04.2.

I upgraded yesterday from 20.04 (php7.4 all working well) and my websites are barely working.  The main symptom is shown here on the login page.  All other symptoms are related. Running php7.4 on the 22.04 also does not work.

Thanks for any help,
Walt

[image: Login Page]

Answer (score 1):

After 20 hours we fond the problem.  There was a line at the bottom of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf that long ago(18.04 ?) helped apache handle php.

SetHandler application/x-httpd-php

After commenting out that line and restarting apache it was all done. 20 hours of hunting and 20 seconds to fix.

#SetHandler application/x-httpd-php

sudo systemctl restart apache2

Comment: Be careful with this type of solution. Most likely you have other problems that are the real source of the issue. Your `<VirtualHost>` is probably misconfigured. This is why you should have posted an update to your question instead of an answer. Someone might help you actually solve your problem. I recommend updating your question with details on the configuration of Apache, PHP and each VirtualHost. Then delete this answer.